# When I use "Connect to Server", how can it remember the IP address?

Tags: shared-folders

I don't want to type in the IP address every single time. Can it just save them to a list or something?

[image]

Comment: Add a DNS server entry, or an entry into `/etc/hosts`?

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the server, and when viewing the directory on the server in Nautilus, simply press `Ctrl+D` to bookmark the location. If you unmount, and then open the bookmark again, it should automatically connect, assuming you opted to store the username/password in your keyring.